# create and use temporary directory in tox

Tags: tox, temporary-directory

I am looking for a reliable method for generating and using temporary, disposable folders, as part of tox environment creation.

```
[testenv:var-test]
description = Try to store output of a shell command
tmpdir = mktemp -d
commands =
    echo {[testenv:var-test]tmpdir}
    # prints "mktemp -d" (command is not run)
    
    tmpdir = mktemp -d
    # ERROR: InvocationError for command could not find executable tmpdir
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways, but you certainly can call a bash script from within the commands section.

**tox.ini**

```
[testenv]
whitelist_externals = bash
commands =
    bash {toxinidir}/commands.sh
```

**commands.sh**

```
TEMP=`mktemp -d`
echo $TEMP
```

**output of a tox run**

```
❯ tox
python run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='562823002'
python run-test: commands[0] | bash /home/jugmac00/stackOverflow/commands.sh
/tmp/tmp.snc2T0Fa6W
_________________________________________________________ summary __________________________________________________________
  python: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

Comment: How can I use the value of `$TEMP` inside the tox testenv? Just creating a folder can be also achieved with `sh -c 'mktemp -d'`.

Comment: Well, there is quite a difference between an inline call to `sh` and calling a bash script, as in the bash script you can work with the output. I think you need to be more specific what you want to do, as you could just put e.g. a second command into the bash script to reuse the tempdir. Where exactly do you want to use the tempdir? Outside of the command section?

Comment: I want to use the tempdir in the commands section and your proposal to delegate everything to an external script is workable. +1